# how to set two volume control in media player for two simultaneously playing sound in android

Tags: android

i am making a media player apps in this apps i want to set two volume control seek bar for controlling two sound clip one is VOICE and another is BACKGROUND SOUND playing simultaneously by making two instance of media player. 
i want to manage there volume separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes... you having two different mediaplayer objects playing at the same time and control their respective volumes... like this..

```
    @Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if(seekBar.equals(s1)){
   //s1 is the seekBar object you have in your activity
       player1.setVolume(progress,progress);


  }
 else{
    player2.setVolume(progress,progress);
  //player1 and player2 are mediaplayers..
 }
}
```

Comment: in the setVolume() methode why you pass same progress variable ??